# Running TensorflowLite on Android Studio - tflite.run() gives the same output for every input

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to run inference in Android Studio on a tensorflow model I created about multi class text classification. However, I have noticed that for every input that I give, the output is the same. Every time. I read in other posts about ppl who have faced the same issue. But trying those out hasn't helped me and most such questions were about image classification, not text classification.

I have attached the code below for both my model and android studio. Please be kind enough to let me know what I am doing wrong. This is my first time running a program like this.

TextClassificationClient.java file is as follows.

```
public class TextClassificationClient {

private static final String TAG = "TextClassificationDemo2";
private static final String MODEL_PATH = "stress_classification_model.tflite";
private static final String DIC_PATH = "words_dict.txt";
private static final String LABEL_PATH = "labels.txt";

private static final int SENTENCE_LEN = 256;
public static Integer MODEL_INPUT_SHAPE = 34746;
private static final String SIMPLE_SPACE_OR_PUNCTUATION = " |\\\\,|\\\\.|\\\\!|\\\\?|\\n";

private static final int MAX_RESULTS = 6;

private final Context context;
private final Map<String, Integer> dic = new HashMap<>();
private final List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
private Interpreter tflite;

public static class Result {

    private final String id;
    private final String title;
    private final Float confidence;

    public Result(String id, String title, Float confidence) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.confidence = confidence;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Float getConfidence() {
        return confidence;
    }

    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String resultString = "";

        if (id != null) {
            resultString += "[" + id + "] ";
        }

        if (title != null) {
            resultString += title + " ";
        }

        if (confidence != null) {
            resultString += String.format("(%.1f%%) ", confidence * 100.0f);
        }

        return resultString.trim();
    }
};

public TextClassificationClient(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@WorkerThread
public void load() {
    loadModel();
    //loadDictionary();
    loadLabels();
}

@WorkerThread
private synchronized void loadModel() {
    try {
        ByteBuffer buffer = loadModelFile(this.context.getAssets());
        tflite = new Interpreter(buffer);
        Log.v(TAG, "TFLite Model Loaded");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.v(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
}

/*@WorkerThread
private synchronized void loadDictionary() {
    try {
        loadDictionaryFile(this.context.getAssets());
        Log.v(TAG, "Dictionary Loaded");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.v(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
}*/

@WorkerThread
private synchronized void loadLabels() {
    try {
        loadLabelFile(this.context.getAssets());
        Log.v(TAG, "Labels Loaded");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.v(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@WorkerThread
private synchronized void unload(){
    tflite.close();
    dic.clear();
    labels.clear();
}

private static MappedByteBuffer loadModelFile(AssetManager assetManager) throws IOException {

    try(AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assetManager.openFd(MODEL_PATH);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor())) {
        FileChannel fileChannel = inputStream.getChannel();
        long startOffset = fileDescriptor.getStartOffset();
        long declaredLength = fileDescriptor.getDeclaredLength();
        return fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, startOffset, declaredLength);
    }
}

private void loadLabelFile(AssetManager assetManager) throws IOException{
    try (InputStream ins = assetManager.open(LABEL_PATH);
         BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins))){
        while (bufferedReader.ready()) {
            labels.add(bufferedReader.readLine());
        }

        System.out.println("Labels are " + labels);
    }
}

/*private void loadDictionaryFile(AssetManager assetManager) throws IOException{
    try (InputStream ins = assetManager.open(DIC_PATH);
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins))){
        while (reader.ready()){
            List<String> line = Arrays.asList(reader.readLine().split(" "));
            if (line.size() < 2){
                continue;
            }

            dic.put(line.get(0).trim(), Integer.parseInt(line.get(1).trim()));
        }
    }
}*/

float[][] tokenizeInputText(String text) throws JSONException {
    String clean_text = text.toLowerCase();
    clean_text = clean_text.replaceAll("[.,:?{}]+", " ");
    clean_text = clean_text.trim();
    System.out.println(clean_text + " is the clean text");
    //float[][] input = new float[1][MODEL_INPUT_SHAPE];

    float[] tmp = new float[130];
    int i = 0;
    JSONObject word_dict = new JSONObject(readJSONFromAsset());

    String[] words = clean_text.split(" ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words) + " is the words var");
    for (String word : words) {

        if (word_dict.has(word)) {
            int index = word_dict.getInt(word);
            System.out.println(index + " is the index inside dic word finding");
            tmp[i++] = index;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tmp) + " is the input before going to classify func");
    Arrays.fill(tmp, i, 130 - 1, 0);
    float[][] ans = {tmp};
    return ans;
}

public String readJSONFromAsset() {
    String json = null;
    try {
        AssetManager assetManager = this.context.getAssets();
        InputStream is = assetManager.open(DIC_PATH);
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return json;
}

@WorkerThread
public synchronized List<Result> classify(String text) throws JSONException {
    //text = "If there is any variation or roadblock to the plan, then I get irritated and anxious. Like for instance, if someone schedules a meeting on my usual naptime.";
    float[][] input = tokenizeInputText(text);

    Log.v(TAG, "Classifying with TFLite");

    float[][] output = new float[1][labels.size()];
    System.out.println("input inside classify in textclient" + Arrays.deepToString(input) + " and labels size is " + labels.size());
    System.out.println("Out put is " + Arrays.deepToString(output));
    System.out.println("Input size is " + input.length);
    tflite.run(input, output);

    System.out.println("Output after running inference is " + Arrays.deepToString(output));

    PriorityQueue<Result> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(
            MAX_RESULTS, (lhs, rhs) -> Float.compare(rhs.getConfidence(), lhs.getConfidence()));
    for(int i = 0; i < labels.size(); i++) {
        pq.add(new Result("" + i, labels.get(i), output[0][i]));
    }

    final ArrayList<Result> results = new ArrayList<>();
    while (!pq.isEmpty()){
        results.add(pq.poll());
    }

    return results;
}

Map<String, Integer> getDic() {
    return this.dic;
}

Interpreter getTflite() {
    return this.tflite;
}

List<String> getLabels(){
    return this.labels;
}

}
```

My MainActivity.java file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "TextClassificationDemo2";
private TextClassificationClient client;

private TextView resultTextView;
private EditText inputEditText;
private Handler handler;
private ScrollView scrollView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.v(TAG, "On Create");

    client = new TextClassificationClient(getApplicationContext());
    handler = new Handler();
    Button classifyButton = findViewById(R.id.button);

    classifyButton.setOnClickListener( (View v) -> {
        classify(inputEditText.getText().toString());
    });

    resultTextView = findViewById(R.id.result_text_view);
    inputEditText = findViewById(R.id.input_text);
    scrollView = findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
}

@Override
protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    Log.v(TAG, "OnStart");
    handler.post(
            () -> {
                client.load();
            }
    );
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    Log.v(TAG, "OnStop");
    handler.post(
            () -> {
                client.load();
            }
    );
}

private void classify(final String text) {

    System.out.println("Text inside classify of Main Activity " + text);
    handler.post(
            () -> {
                List<TextClassificationClient.Result> results = null;
                try {
                    results = client.classify(text);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                showResult(text, results);
            }
    );
}

private void showResult(final String inputText, final List<TextClassificationClient.Result> results){
    runOnUiThread(
            () -> {
                String textToShow = "Input : " + inputText + "\nOutput : \n";
                for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
                    TextClassificationClient.Result result = results.get(i);
                    textToShow += String.format("    %s: %s\\n", result.getTitle(), result.getConfidence());
                }

                textToShow += "---------\\n";

                resultTextView.append(textToShow);
                inputEditText.getText().clear();

                scrollView.post(() -> scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN));
            }
    );
}
}
```

My python model developed.

```
data = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Dataset/TestforNLP3.csv')

data.head()

data.Subreddit.value_counts()

data.Text=data.Text.astype(str)

data.loc[data['Subreddit'] == 'Divorce', 'LABEL'] = 0
data.loc[data['Subreddit'] == 'CPTSD', 'LABEL'] = 1
data.loc[data['Subreddit'] == 'Anxiety', 'LABEL'] = 2
data.loc[data['Subreddit'] == 'Suicide', 'LABEL'] = 3
data.loc[data['Subreddit'] == 'Depression', 'LABEL'] = 4
data.loc[data['Subreddit'] == 'Breakups', 'LABEL'] = 5
print(data['LABEL'][:10])
data.head()

data['LABEL']

labels = to_categorical(data['LABEL'], num_classes=6)
print(labels[:10])
if 'Subreddit' in data.keys():
   data.drop(['Subreddit'], axis=1)

data.head()

#data = pd.concat([e,b,t,m], ignore_index=True)
#data = data.reindex(np.random.permutation(data.index))

n_most_common_words = 8000
max_len = 130
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=n_most_common_words, filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data['Text'].values)
sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data['Text'].values)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print('Found %s unique tokens.' % len(word_index))

X = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=max_len)

print(X)

X = X.astype('float32')


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X , labels, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

epochs = 50
emb_dim = 128
batch_size = 256
labels[:2]

print((X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape))

def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(n_most_common_words, emb_dim, input_length=X.shape[1]))
    model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.5))
    model.add(LSTM(64, dropout=0.5, recurrent_dropout=0.5))
    model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
    print(model.summary())
    return model

model = create_model()

from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=8)
model = create_model()

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size,validation_split=0.2,callbacks=[early_stopping])
model.save('model.h5')
```

And to convert the model to tflite I used this.

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import load_model

tflite_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(tflite_model)
tflite_save = converter.convert()
open("stress_classification_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_save)
```

The model works quite well in colab (where i ran it). But when it comes to running it on Android Studio, it gives the same output to all inputs.

```
I/System.out: Text inside classify of Main Activity i am so anxious all the time i think i have anxiety issues
I/System.out: i am so anxious all the time i think i have anxiety issues is the clean text
I/example.mltest: Background concurrent copying GC freed 12938(655KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(36KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 4MB/8MB, paused 1.663ms total 114.711ms
I/System.out: [i, am, so, anxious, all, the, time, i, think, i, have, anxiety, issues] is the words var
1 is the index inside dic word finding
I/System.out: 54 is the index inside dic word finding
21 is the index inside dic word finding
372 is the index inside dic word finding
I/System.out: 36 is the index inside dic word finding
4 is the index inside dic word finding
51 is the index inside dic word finding
1 is the index inside dic word finding
76 is the index inside dic word finding
1 is the index inside dic word finding
17 is the index inside dic word finding
I/System.out: 117 is the index inside dic word finding
293 is the index inside dic word finding
I/System.out: [1.0, 54.0, 21.0, 372.0, 36.0, 4.0, 51.0, 1.0, 76.0, 1.0, 17.0, 117.0, 293.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] is the input before going to classify func
V/TextClassificationDemo2: Classifying with TFLite
I/System.out: input inside classify in textclient[[1.0, 54.0, 21.0, 372.0, 36.0, 4.0, 51.0, 1.0, 76.0, 1.0, 17.0, 117.0, 293.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]] and labels size is 6
I/System.out: Out put is [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
Input size is 1
I/System.out: Output after running inference is [[0.038896494, 0.060354583, 0.1140039, 0.35273075, 0.13279961, 0.3012147]]
I/Choreographer: Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1232ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=3265209438231, Vsync=3266326104853, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=3266329047000, AnimationStart=3266329152100, PerformTraversalsStart=3266331470500, DrawStart=3266377262000, SyncQueued=3266383669900, SyncStart=3266383767900, IssueDrawCommandsStart=3266383890600, SwapBuffers=3266426132700, FrameCompleted=3266441848500, DequeueBufferDuration=1990000, QueueBufferDuration=7909000, 
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
I/System.out: Text inside classify of Main Activity please help me i am so depressed
I/System.out: please help me i am so depressed is the clean text
I/System.out: [please, help, me, i, am, so, depressed] is the words var
403 is the index inside dic word finding
I/System.out: 114 is the index inside dic word finding
8 is the index inside dic word finding
1 is the index inside dic word finding
54 is the index inside dic word finding
21 is the index inside dic word finding
365 is the index inside dic word finding
I/System.out: [403.0, 114.0, 8.0, 1.0, 54.0, 21.0, 365.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0] is the input before going to classify func
V/TextClassificationDemo2: Classifying with TFLite
I/System.out: input inside classify in textclient[[403.0, 114.0, 8.0, 1.0, 54.0, 21.0, 365.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]] and labels size is 6
Out put is [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
Input size is 1
I/System.out: Output after running inference is [[0.0388965, 0.060354587, 0.11400388, 0.3527307, 0.1327996, 0.30121475]]
```

Any help would be really appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you  try to test the tflite model using the python Interpreter?

Comment: @koltun yes I did. I found out the problem was in how I'm padding my input array before feeding it to tflite.run(). In my model I had started padding at the front. But in my android code I had started padding at the back. So the input will be different. Thank you for commenting!